# updating multiple text file at once

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating an app using flash cc. I need to create couple of text files to save some data. I can create and save some data into text file but I can only update one file at a time. I've used the following code:

```
for(var i:int = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        var file:File;
        file = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("myApp/" + this["folder" + i] + "/playinfo.txt");

        var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
        stream.writeUTFBytes("something");
        stream.close();
    }
```

The above code seems to edit only the last file. What am I doing wrong ? Any help would be appreciated. I'm also thinking of using timer instead of for-loop to update single text file at a time.Which approach would be better ? Or is there any better solution to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the object `this` is in context of (`this["folder" + i]`), but removing the `this` reference and using `folder + i` will result in:

```
myApp
├── folder1
│   └── playinfo.txt
├── folder2
│   └── playinfo.txt
├── folder3
│   └── playinfo.txt
├── folder4
│   └── playinfo.txt
└── folder5
    └── playinfo.txt
```

So your code snippet becomes:

```
    for(var i:int = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        var file:File;
        file = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("myApp/" + "folder" + i + "/playinfo.txt");
        trace(file.toString());
        var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
        stream.writeUTFBytes("something");
        stream.close();
    }
```

Comment: this["folder" + i] includes folder names. As you mentioned above, the folder structure gonna look like same but with different folder names

Comment: So in context, what does `this` resolve to? (Debugger or just a trace statement?)

Comment: It's string variable. It holds bunch of chapter names.

Comment: A `string`? Seems like you should be using an `Array` (or `Vector`) since you are accessing it like one. var chapternames:Array = new Array("Stasis", "Trigger", "Quest");` then you can use `"myApp/" + chapternames[i] + ...`

Comment: Yes, I can use Array.